# how to understand curly brace inside square brackets in string format python code for removing punctuation

Tags: python, string, replace

Could someone explain to me what `'[{}]'` does in the code below? I know the code is for removing punctuation, but why exactly it has to be curly brace inside square brackets?

Is there any pattern? Is there any other similar convention or tips for using it?

```py
df[colname] = df[colname].str.replace('[{}]'.format(string.punctuation), '')
```

Why it would return error if I use:

```py
df[colname] = df[colname].apply(lambda x: x.replace(string.punctuation,'')
```

Comment: your use case is to remove all punctuation in a pandas dataframe column?

Comment: `x.replace(string.punctuation,'')` would replace the *entirety* of `string.punctuation`, if found contiguously in `x`.  It wouldn't replace any individual punctuation characters.  `'[{}]'.format(string.punctuation)` is a failed attempt at making a regular expression that matches any one punctuation character - it doesn't work because some of those characters would require escaping to be meaningful in a regex.

Comment: The `{}` is a form of string formatting. It gets replaced by the value in the `format` function

Comment: yes, but i think i know what goes wrong for that @bigbounty

Comment: Thank you, i noticed that one as well. I added back slash before some characters. Now I am using ```df[column].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'[!\"#$%&\'()*+,-.\/:;<=>?\@[\\]^_`{|}~]+', '', x))``` and it seems working? would you please elaborate on the escaping thing? like what characters need that and is it same as I added back slash before the special characters? if I want to learn it, would you recommend some keywords to search for? Thank you very much @jasonharper

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone explain to me what `'[{}]'` does in the code below? I know the code is for removing punctuation, but why exactly it has to be curly brace inside square brackets?

You are looking at too small of a code segment. To understand what is going on here, you need to look at the context of this string and how it is used:

```
'[{}]'.format(string.punctuation)
```

The [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format) function defines its own [mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatspec) to interpret the string. In this case the `{}` is a place holder that will be replaced by the argument to `format()`. The `[` and `]` are just literal characters.

We can run this in a Python REPL session to see the result:

```
>>> import string
>>> '[{}]'.format(string.punctuation)
'[!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~]'
>>>
```

The exact output might differ for you depending on the character set and locale settings on your machine.